# how to handle exceptions in MVCMailer in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcmailer

I'm using MVCMailer for the first time.
I have created the mailviewmodel, view and i was able to send the mail successfully.

```
_myMailer.SendMyMail(mailerModel).Send();
```

Now I want to catch an exception when email sending is failed. (When no internet connection is available)
I tried to use

```
var client = new SmtpClientWrapper();
client.SendCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Error != null || e.Cancelled)
    {
        // Handle Error
    }

    //Use e.UserState
};
```

which is in [GitHub](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide)

but this didn't work for me. can anybody please tell me how to achieve this?

Immediate replies appriciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is for Asynchronous Email. You are sending synchronous.

**Edit**

You can try this:

```
try
{
    _myMailer.SendMyMail(mailerModel).Send();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to do this in Synchronous mail sending?